# start autocomplete service as soon as page loads

Tags: angular, rxjs

Two questions!

Is there a way for me to have all the values show from my service as soon as the page loads. Currently I first have to click inside the search field and start typing for it to show the values. I have tried `startWith('')` but it gives me this error:

> ERROR in src/app/computer-view/computer-view.component.ts(39,4): error
>   TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'.   Type '{}' is not assignable to type
>   'ComputerInfo[]'.
>       Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'.

Also I am using a `.filter` and `.includes` to filter through an array, it can match either the code or name element in my array. When it finds the element it returns an array with the values that evaluated to true which is what I want. But I was also wondering if its possible to get back the actual value that matched the includes so I can bind it to another html element. In other words showing what exactly matched (name or code), I want to bind it where I show the serial number. 
Thanks

```js
import { CasperComputersService } from '../services/casper-computers.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Subscription,Observable, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import {
  map,
  withLatestFrom,
  debounceTime,
  startWith
} from "rxjs/operators";
import { ComputerInfo } from './../models/computer-info';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-computer-view',
  templateUrl: './computer-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./computer-view.component.css']
})
export class ComputerViewComponent implements OnInit {

computerSearchForm: FormGroup;

computers: ComputerInfo[]= [];
compSub: Subscription;
private computerSubj = new BehaviorSubject(this.computers);
computerSearch: Observable<ComputerInfo[]>;
  constructor(public computerService: CasperComputersService,
  private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.computerSearchForm=this.fb.group({
      computerSearch: ''
    });
   this.computerService.getGeneralComputers();
   this.compSub = this.computerService.getComputerUpdateListener()
   .subscribe(comp=>{
     this.computers = comp;
     this.computerSubj.next([...this.computers]);
   });
   this.computerSearch = this.inputChange("computerSearch");
  }
  private inputChange(control: string) {
    return this.computerSearchForm.get(control).valueChanges.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.computerSubj),
      debounceTime(500),
      map(x => {
        return this._filter(x);
      })
    );
  }

  private _filter(term): ComputerInfo[] {
    if (term[0] === ''){return term[1].map(option=>{return option})};
    const filterValue: string = term[0].toString().trim(' ').toLowerCase();
    return term[1].filter(option =>
      option.id.toString().trim(' ').toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) || option.name.toLowerCase().trim(' ').includes(filterValue)
    );
  }


}
```

```js
<mat-card>
<form [formGroup]="computerSearchForm">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input  mat-raised type="text" id="computerSearch" name="computerSearch" matInput formControlName="computerSearch">
      </mat-form-field>
      </form>
  <ul *ngFor="let computer of computerSearch|async">

  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{computer.name}}

      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description style="text-align: center">
        <p>{{computer.serial_number}}</p>
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <p>{{computer.id}}</p>
    <p>{{computer.serial_number}}</p>
    <p>{{computer.udid}}</p>
    <p>{{computer.mac_address}}</p>

  </mat-expansion-panel>
</ul>


</mat-card>
```

Comment: If you're using Angular Material, why don't you use [Material autocomplete component](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) ?

Comment: I mean the issue is the same, I just wanted to filter out my accordion as the user types. I’ve built the exact same component for a different project (I just changed the names and switched from the autocomplete module) and it still does the same thing. The only difference is that it doesnt really matter for my other project.